# Bybit API InvalidRequestError: Missing required parameter 'type'

Tags: bybit, python-bybit

I get the above error when trying to execute an order through pybit.

Reading the [docs](https://bybit-exchange.github.io/docs/spot/v3/#t-introduction) I'm not aware of a parameter called "type" or what it refers to. Does anyone know what I need to do to my code to execute an order?

```
    session.place_active_order(symbol= "BTCUSDT", 
            qty= BTCsell_qty, 
            side= "Sell", 
            order_type= "Limit", 
            time_in_force= "GoodTillCancel",
            price= BTCMarketPrice)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you cover the Required fields like close_on_trigger.
Include Position_idx if in one way mode.
I generally use Conditional Trigger Orders for Limit orders